# Yii - Inheriting From Custom Controller Class - Not Found

Tags: php, yii, gii

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{

        public function actionIndex() {
                echo 'This is some controller';
        }
}


class AnotherController extends SomeController
{

        public function actionIndex() {
                echo 'This is another controller';
        }
}
```

This works:

```
index.php?r=some
```

but ...

```
index.php?r=another
```

says:

> PHP warning
>
> include(SomeController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Both of the files are in

```
test\protected\controllers\
```

BTW in the past I also tried using the Gii Controller Generator with "SomeController" as the base class...

It said:

```
The controller has been generated successfully. You may try it now.

Generating code using template 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\gii\generators\controller\templates\default"...
generated controllers\YetAnotherController.php
generated views\yetAnother\index.php
done!
```

When I clicked on "try it now" it also said:

> PHP warning
>
> include(SomeController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:**

Classes inside *protected/controllers* are not autoloaded, therefore you'll have to import the parent class file before extending from it:

In *AnotherController.php*:

```
Yii::import('application.controllers.SomeController');
public class AnotherController extends SomeController {
    // ...
}
```

Incase you need to access the base class from url also, you can use the above method. Otherwise you can put your base class inside *protected/components* as you have already figured out.

---

Yii autoloading works only when you have the same name for the file as the class that the file contains. Meaning `class SomeController` should be within *SomeController.php* file.

Make those changes and it should work.

A helpful wiki: [Understanding Autoloading Helper Classes and Helper functions](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/165/understanding-autoloading-helper-classes-and-helper-functions/).

[Guide link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.convention#file):

> Class files should be named after the public class they contain.

Comment: Yep it's in \protected\controllers\SomeController.php BTW like I said "http://localhost/yii/testapp/index.php?r=some" works... But gii's "YetAnotherController.php" (index.php?r=yetAnother) and my "AnotherController.php" (index.php?r=another) give errors about their base class (SomeController.php). There seems to be a problem with the autoloading of SomeController.php when it is the base class but it works fine if I'm using index.php?r=some. Also I'm getting the same error when I'm referencing Post.php within a controller... it is in models/Post.php...

Comment: oh ok, then will you be accessing the base controller from url? or is it just a base class, and you wish to only use it as such?

Comment: Sorry it looks like the base class is meant to go in /components/ - I wasn't reading the ebook properly.

Comment: yes but then you wont be able to use it from url, for that you'll have to import

Comment: see update to use controller both from url and as a base class

Comment: This has to be one of the most aggravating things about Yii.

Answer (score 3):

To extend any class just go to the config file and add the class in the import section

`'import' => array('application.controllers.SomeController')`

this will make it available in the entire application without importing explicitly.